# Scrolling to a particular div

Tags: html

I have an html page with three divs containing text content. I want to scroll to a particular div depending upon the link that the user clicks on the home page.

There are three links on the home page; so what I want is if the user clicks on link 1 he is scrolled to div 1 on the resultant page, if he clicks on link 2 on the home page, then the page is scrolled to div 2 on resultant page and so on.

Comment: This is basic html, not JS or CSS.  Read about the `name` attribute on W3Schools: [HTML Links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp). As noted there, you can use the `id` attribute on all modern browsers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly google before posting your queries here.

Comment: If you mean **animated** scrolling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: @merv [Why you shouldn't use w3schools.com](http://w3fools.com) - Link the official [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) instead. And for this special case the [link section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

Answer (score 4):

> If you want to scroll the current document to a particular place, the
>   value of HREF should be the name of the anchor to which to scroll,
>   preceded by the # sign. If you want to open another document at an
>   anchor, give the URL for the document, followed by #, followed by the
>   name of the anchor.

Use a bookmark with the anchor tag:

```
<a href="results.html#first-div">First</a>
<a href="results.html#second-div">Second</a>
<a href="results.html#third-div">Third</a>
```

You would just substitute the value after the '#' symbol to the appropriate element IDs.

Reference: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/1998/htmlguide/tags7.html

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method is using [Fragment Identifier](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#scroll-to-fragid). Whenever you are creating links, attach the id of the element you want to scroll to, on the end of link. For example:

```
link.html#divToScrollTo
```

An example usage:

```
<a href="link.html#divToScrollTo">Scroll to div with divToScrollTo as id</a>
```

After clicking on this link, the browser to first navigate to `link.html` and then scroll to an element with `divToScrollTo` Link.

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all new browsers also support the id as an anchor destination

`<div id="div1">...</div>`

Will respond to `<a href="page2.html#div1">...</a>`

as well as the name attribute does